# How to load JS at the very end

Tags: javascript, wordpress

after hours of research I did not find a way to execute my JS script after the script that creates the popup "Just a Moment" ( http://wpd-test2.onlinegurus.de/wpd/design/8/ )

Is there a way to make sure my JS script is executes after the "Just a moment" JS?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: All of your relevant code should be posted here. It helps everyone out.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can do it only if you control the "just a moment" script. You can do a trick to activate a script when you load another. Like this:

```
function loadScript( url, callback ) {
  var script = document.createElement( "script" )
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  if(script.readyState) {  //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ( script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete" ) {
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
        callback();
      }
    };
  } else {  //Others
    script.onload = function() {
      callback();
    };
  }

  script.src = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( script );
}
```

You can test it with

```
loadScript(PathToJustAMoment, function() {
  alert('script ready!'); 
});
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I dont control the "just a moment" script. In WordPress, I added every available script as a dependency. But that didn't solve the problem :(